# Javascript / Positioning an element

Tags: javascript, html-table, position

I've got a table and a hidden div. 
Here it is:

[image]

The div's position is detected by CSS, it is static (it appears in the same place when I click on any cell). But I want the div to be positioned dynamically every time I click on the table's cell. In other words, I need the div to appear by the clicked cell.

Of course, I can give the table "position: relative" and the div "position: absolute",  and then set the div's "top"/"bottom" and "left"/"right" every time I click on a cell. But is there any easier (= more readable code) way to code? I have to use **native Javascript ONLY** to solve the issue.

UPD! Here is the code I suppose to use every time when clicking on a cell:
'addevent' = my div

```
var cell = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for (var i=0; i<cell.length; i++) {
cell[i].onclick = function() {
editEvent = document.getElementById('addevent');
editEvent.style.cssText ="display: block; position: absolute; top: 300px; left: 240px;";

};
```

Comment: Two things. First, you'll need to post a code example in your question, not just a picture. Second, people still listen to Limp Bizkit?

Comment: Without an example of your own approach, it's hard to say whether a better one exists.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done.  You just have to apply `position: relative` to the `td` instead of the `table` and make the popup a child of the `td`. The following example uses pseudo-elements, but you can easily use a `div` that you add `display:block` to on click of the `td`.

```css
html, body, table {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    padding: 2em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

td {
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}

td:hover:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    border: 1em solid transparent;
    border-right-color: #C55;
    border-left-width: 0;
}

td:hover:after {
    content: 'test popup';
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #C55;
    color: white;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-left: 1em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>*</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>*</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>*</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>*</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>*</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```